# how to use RewriteRule URL in 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My current url structure is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_([^/]*).uz$    postview.php?url=$1&authorurl=$2 [L]
```

Now I want to use slash instead of underscore, like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*).uz$    postview.php?url=$1&authorurl=$2 [L]
```

How can I redirect my old url to new url?

I tried like this,

```
Redirect 301 ^([^/]*)_([^/]*).uz$ ^([^/]*)/([^/]*).uz$
```

not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Redirect` rule you are using a regex pattern both in source and target URLs, besides `Redirect` doesn't even accept regular expressions.

You can do it like this using all `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^.]+\.uz)$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.uz$ postview.php?url=$1&authorurl=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: small issue, it is redirecting to root folder not the current one. example: `localhost/site/title_author.uz` redirecting to `localhost/title/author.uz` how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below too,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]+)_([^/]+).uz$
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2.uz [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).uz$
RewriteRule ^ postview.php?url=%1&authorurl=%2 [L]
```